# "Website: Not a valid URL format" when creating an application of twitter

Tags: iphone, twitter

I'd like to create an application that can integrate with Twitter.
So I went to the website: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new to create an application.

But the WebSite: field always failed. It said that "Website: Not a valid URL format".
I tried different "valid" URLs, but failed.

Do you have any ideas on the twitter application?

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Comment: Might help if you told us what you put in which failed.

Comment: It's easy to reproduce the issue in the website I mentioned above. Just input any words for the application name, description, and then the website. It will fail, anyway.

Comment: I tried many times, and it failed every time, even with a valid URL.

Comment: if your URL is "http://something.com" make it  "http://something.com/"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mine is working. Save it in this format `http://url.com`. Even this `domain.com` works.

You can try doing it in a different browser, logout and login.

[image: M]

Comment: i have add this details same.. i can able to successfully but after that it will display web page is not available

Answer (score 28):

I was trying to set localhost URL and got the same error message.

After replacing

http://`localhost`
http://`localhost`/twitter/callback

with

http://`127.0.0.1`
http://`127.0.0.1`/twitter/callback

it let me saved my test application

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was in trailing whitespace from copy/paste.

Comment: That was exactly my case. Thank you!

Comment: That was my case too, your reply saved my life :D

Answer (score 4):

One easy mistake to make is both the callback url and website need to start with `http://`

This worked for me:

```
WebSite: http://example.com

CallbackURL: http://example.com/auth/twitter/callback/
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to make applications if I include "http://" at the beginning. Also it might be something browser related (I'm using Chrome) so check that.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same Issue, then after googling, someone said that:

"I think your website and callback should match. Some examples:

website: http://www.quoteicon.com
callback: http://www.quoteicon.com/twitter/callback "

summarizing **the field callback has to be prefixed with the website**, otherwise it gets error that the URL is invalid!
and they dont accept local IPs to the webSite fields.

It worked for me, hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I ran into this today.  Twitter does not allow localhost or IP addresses in the URL (plus it does require http:// or https:// as a prefix).

However this doesn't help with local debugging.

So an easy workaround is to add something like myapp.here.com in your /etc/hosts file

`127.0.0.1     myapp.here.com`

and then enter http://myapp.here.com and http://myapp.here.com/auth/twitter in the fields.
That should allow local debugging.  It is odd as Facebook makes this a bit easier and it seems like a common task for debugging these types of integrations.

You could even override your actual domain locally if you wanted to use the same Twitter App ID.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of localhost, if you are developing on local machine. Twitter doesn't allow url with `http://localhost:3000` or without http.

I'm wonder, why ;] Hope, They will add it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I didn't have a problem with my callback url at all, but the error message was for the Website url!

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything now, eventually only `https://example.com/auth` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added www and the error was gone.

**Previously**
http://twitter.com/...

**After**
http://www.twitter.com/...

Answer (score -1):

This issue is resolved when I give my Website & Callback URL same htt://URL.Hope it will help to resolve your solution.